# Drawing square colour stored in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, pygame, game-development

I am trying to draw a checkerboard. However when I call the 'drawBoard' function it returns a black screen. I think the problem may be this line here:

```
colour = con.BOARD_COLOURS[((r+c) % 2)]
```

I was attempting to index the different colour values using either 0 or 1 in order to alternate the colour of the squares as they are drawn. Could any one explain where I am going wrong. Below is the full code:

```
#Defining constants

# RGB colours
BOARD_COLOURS = [(245, 222, 179),(34, 139, 34)]

# Dimensions
ROWS = 8
COLS = 8
DIMS = 600
SQUARE = 600 // 8
```

```
class Board:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def drawBoard(self, screen):
        for r in range(con.ROWS):
            for c in range(con.ROWS):
                colour = con.BOARD_COLOURS[((r+c) % 2)]
                pg.draw.rect(screen, colour, pg.Rect(c*con.SQUARE, r*con.SQUARE, con.SQUARE, con.SQUARE))
```

```
def main():
    t = 60
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    interface = pg.display.set_mode((con.DIMS, con.DIMS))

    pg.init()
    run = True

    while run:
        clock.tick(t)

        for ev in pg.event.get():
            if ev.type == pg.QUIT:
                run = False

        b = Board()
        b.drawBoard(interface)

    pg.quit()
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the display. Update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) after drawing the scene:

```py
def main():
    t = 60
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    interface = pg.display.set_mode((con.DIMS, con.DIMS))

    pg.init()
    b = Board()

    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(t)
        for ev in pg.event.get():
            if ev.type == pg.QUIT:
                run = False

        interface.fill(0)
        b.drawBoard(interface)
        pygame.display.flip()

    pg.quit()
main()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

---

To drag the objects you have to implement the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`, `MOUSEBUTTONUP` and `MOUSEMOTION` event:

```py
def main():
    t = 60
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    interface = pg.display.set_mode((DIMS, DIMS))

    pg.init()
    pg.display.set_caption("Checkers Game")

    dragitem = None
    run = True
    b = Board()
    while run:
        clock.tick(t)

        for ev in pg.event.get():
            if ev.type == pg.QUIT:
                run = False

            if ev.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                col = ev.pos[0] * COLS // DIMS
                row = ev.pos[1] * ROWS // DIMS
                if b.board[row][col] > 1:
                    dragitem = (row, col, b.board[row][col])
                    b.board[row][col] = (row + col) % 2 == 0
                    dragpos = ev.pos
            if ev.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                new_col = ev.pos[0] * COLS // DIMS
                new_row = ev.pos[1] * ROWS // DIMS
                if b.board[new_row][new_col] < 2:
                    b.board[new_row][new_col] = dragitem[2]
                else:
                    b.board[dragitem[0]][dragitem[1]] = dragitem[2]
                dragpos = None
                dragitem = None
            if ev.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION and dragitem:
                dragpos = ev.pos

        interface.fill(0)
        b.drawBoard(interface)
        b.drawPiece(interface)
        if dragitem:
            pg.draw.circle(interface, PIECE_COLOUR[dragitem[2]-2], dragpos, RADIUS)
        pg.display.flip()

    pg.quit()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful! How did you manage to keep the pieces in the centre of the square? Did you you create a function for this? @Rabbid76

Comment: @dextrin No. The secret is `new_col = ev.pos[0] * COLS // DIMS` `new_row = ev.pos[1] * ROWS // DIMS` (under `if ev.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:`). The piece is just removed from its old position `b.board[row][col] = (row + col) % 2 == 0` and put to the new position `b.board[new_row][new_col] = dragitem[2]`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate the help.